# Enhanced Video Renderer snapshot image is empty

Tags: c++, image, directshow, snapshot, renderer

I am trying to use the enhanced video renderer to take a snapshot, image of the current rendered stream. I am able to display a video feed either from a file or capture card. When I run

```
if (pDisplay)
{
    BITMAPINFOHEADER lpHeader = { 0 };
    BYTE* lpCurrImage = NULL;
    DWORD bitmapSize = 0;
    LONGLONG timestamp = 0;
    lpHeader.biSize = sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER);

    if (SUCCEEDED(hr = pDisplay->GetCurrentImage(&lpHeader, &lpCurrImage, &bitmapSize, &timestamp)))
    {
```

the output image data is 0, see image below:
[image]

For some reason, when I use VMR7 or 9, the image works fine and has data (rendering the same video) however EVR does not get an image. The bitmap that outputs is 14kb (which is the header information).

For more info, here is the code that I use to render the EVR:

```
HRESULT InitializeWindowlessEVR(IGraphBuilder* pGraph, IBaseFilter** ppEVR)
{
    IBaseFilter* pEvr = NULL;
    CComPtr<IMFGetService> pServices;
    CComPtr<IMFQualityAdvise2> pAdvise;

    if (!ppEVR)
        return E_POINTER;
    *ppEVR = NULL;

    // Create the VMR and add it to the filter graph.
    HRESULT hr = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_EnhancedVideoRenderer, NULL,
        CLSCTX_INPROC, IID_IBaseFilter, (void**)&pEvr);
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        hr = pGraph->AddFilter(pEvr, L"Enhanced Video Renderer");
        if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
        {
            // Update the window settings
            CHECK_HR(pEvr->QueryInterface(IID_IMFGetService, (void**)&pServices));
            CHECK_HR(pServices->GetService(MR_VIDEO_RENDER_SERVICE, IID_IMFVideoDisplayControl, (void**)&pVideoDisplay));
            CHECK_HR(pVideoDisplay->SetVideoWindow(ghApp));
            CHECK_HR(pVideoDisplay->SetAspectRatioMode(MFVideoARMode_PreservePicture));
        }

        pEvr->AddRef();
        *ppEVR = pEvr;
        pEvr->Release();
        pEvr = NULL;
    }
done:
    return hr;
}
```

Please help me figure out why I am unable to get an image for EVR, I do not want to go back and use VMR9. I can post more code if it helps. Thanks in advance!

**Answer:**

```
BOOL CaptureImage(LPCTSTR szFile)
{
    if (pVideoDisplay)
    {
        BYTE* lpCurrImage = NULL;
        BITMAPINFOHEADER lpHeader = { 0 };
        DWORD bitmapSize = 0;
        LONGLONG timestamp = 0;
        lpHeader.biSize = sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER);

        if (SUCCEEDED(pVideoDisplay->GetCurrentImage(&lpHeader, &lpCurrImage, &bitmapSize, &timestamp)))
        {
            // Create a new file to store the bitmap data
            HANDLE hFile = CreateFile(szFile, GENERIC_WRITE, FILE_SHARE_READ, NULL,
                CREATE_ALWAYS, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, 0);

            if (hFile == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
                return FALSE;

            DWORD dwWritten;
            BITMAPFILEHEADER fileHeader;
            fileHeader.bfOffBits = sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER) + sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER);
            fileHeader.bfReserved1 = 0;
            fileHeader.bfReserved2 = 0;
            fileHeader.bfSize = sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER) + sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER) + lpHeader.biSizeImage;
            fileHeader.bfType = 0x4d42;

            // Write the bitmap header and bitmap bits to the file
            WriteFile(hFile, (LPCVOID)&fileHeader, sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER), &dwWritten, 0);
            WriteFile(hFile, (LPCVOID)&lpHeader, sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER), &dwWritten, 0);
            WriteFile(hFile, (LPCVOID)lpCurrImage, bitmapSize, &dwWritten, 0);

            CloseHandle(hFile);

            CoTaskMemFree(lpCurrImage);
            return TRUE;
        }
        else
        {
            return FALSE;
        }
    }
    return FALSE;
}
```

Comment: It looks good - the call succeeds and you have output. 14 KB just cannot be header. What you definitely do wrong is casting from `lpCurrImage` to `pdib`. Unlike other `GetCurrentImage` methods, this one gets you `BITMAPINFOHEADER` separately and not as a part of payload data output.

Comment: Do you know how I can save it to file then? When I save the image directly (with the header info), the image becomes an readable unlike vmr7/9.

Comment: You get the same information as in case of VMR 7/9, just separate parts: header and data. With VMR-7/9 you have them in one piece. So you need to simply update your saving respectively: write header, then pixels. Prefix this with file header, if you need a `.BMP` file.

Comment: Thanks! I got it, I posted my code in the post above.